# How to create an update after insert Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

hello please i want to creat a trigger after insert on a table, the purpose of this trigger is to update a row on the same table, here is the code i wrote, im using phpmyadmin :

```
 UPDATE commande SET NEW.CodeLivreurClient= SHA1(concat(NEW.IdCommande,"_",NEW.DateCommande,"_",NEW.HoraireCommande,"_",NEW.IdClient))
```

the table is the following :

```
  CREATE TABLE `commande` (
     `IdCommande` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `DateCommande` date NOT NULL,
     `HoraireCommande` time NOT NULL,
     `MethodePaiement` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
     `StatusPaiement` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
     `StatusCommande` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
     `CodeLivreurRestaurant` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
     `CodeLivreurClient` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
     `IdLivreur` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `IdClient` int(11) NOT NULL
   )
```

The trigger is:

```
CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost TRIGGER Apres_Insert_Commande
    AFTER INSERT ON commande
    FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE commande
    SET NEW.CodeLivreurClien t= SHA1(concat(NEW.IdCommande,"", NEW.DateCommande,"", NEW.HoraireCommande, "_", NEW.IdClient));
```

Comment: You haven't written a trigger.  It is quite unclear what you want to do.

Comment: this is the full code of the trigger i wrote :

Comment: CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `Apres_Insert_Commande` AFTER INSERT ON `commande` FOR EACH ROW UPDATE commande SET NEW.CodeLivreurClient= SHA1(concat(NEW.IdCommande,"_",NEW.DateCommande,"_",NEW.HoraireCommande,"_",NEW.IdClient));

Comment: @GordonLinoff any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: You cannot update 'the same' table from the trigger. I'd recommend you to rid off the id from your hash and then you will be able to do everything in BEFORE INSERT trigger.

Comment: Also, you have syntax error in your trigger create clause: 'NEW.CodeLivreurClien t' must be 'NEW.CodeLivreurClient'.